# Digamma function property

Tags: summation, digamma-function

I am trying to determine $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(\alpha\cdot n+1)^2}
$, to do this I will use the following property that I cannot prove, any ideas?

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(\alpha n+1)^2}=\frac1{\alpha^2}\psi'\left(\frac1\alpha\right)
$$

I know some properties about the digamma function but almost none about its derivative, I need some idea to start since I can only think of deriving the definition $\psi(z)=\dfrac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$.

Comment: Derivatives of digamma function are expressible as Hurwitz zeta functions.

Answer (score 2):

The $m$th derivative of the digamma function is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) of order $m$, $\psi^{(m)}(z)$. The polygamma function has the series representation $$\psi^{(m)}(z) = (-1)^{m+1}m! \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+n)^{m+1}},$$ so writing $(\alpha n+1)^2 = \alpha^2\left(n+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)^2$ (and taking $m = 1$) gives your series.

This series expansion follows directly from the recurrence relation $$\psi^{(m)}(z+1) = \psi^{(m)}(z) + \frac{(-1)^m m!}{z^{m+1}},$$ which we obtain by differentiating ($m$ times) the corresponding recurrence relation for the digamma function, $$\psi(z+1) = \psi(z) + \frac{1}{z}$$

Answer (score 1):

Maple evaluates these:
$$
\psi'\left(1\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\\
\psi'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{2}
\\
\psi'\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = \pi^2 + 8\;\text{Catalan}
$$
but no others among $\psi'(1/k)$ with $k$ up to $20$.

Comment: $\psi'(1/k)$ (or $\psi_1(1/k)$) may be written as sum of Clausen functions $\operatorname{Cl}_2(f \pi)$ : see $(22)$ and next at [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html). Excellent new year 2024,

Comment: ( the [general formula is $(14)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html) )

Comment: I think $\operatorname{Cl}_2$ is less well known that $\psi'$.

Comment: You are probably right but generalizations of [Gauss's digamma theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss's_digamma_theorem) like $(14)$ are somewhat neat and provide some hints to why finding other $\psi'(1/k)$ expressions is hard. Cheers,